# Retrieving values and attributes from XML using XPath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

Junior .NET C# self-learner here. I've 'lost' a day today trying to wrap my head around XPath, XPath expressions, XPathDocument, XPathNodeIterator, and XPathNavigator. I think I must be doing something wrong because I can't believe it's this difficult to get names, values, and attributes from an XML document.

I was able to achieve my intended goal in PowerShell in just a few lines, in less than 10 minutes. Yet this has taken me an entire day and I still feel totally lost.

Can someone please help by:

1. Confirming I'm on the right lines and not doing something completely crazy.
2. Telling me if there's a simpler way to do this.
3. Assisting me with getting the missing value/attributes.

Here's my XML document: https://gist.github.com/arbitmcdonald/3c5381e920fac7b880df68912bfddbd9

The data we're interested in (from the linked file above) are these bad boys:

```
<cdf:rule-result severity="medium" weight="10.0" time="2022-05-28T23:12:16" version="DTBI014-IE11" idref="xccdf_mil.disa.stig_rule_SV-59337r8_rule">
      <cdf:result>fail</cdf:result>
      <cdf:ident system="http://iase.disa.mil/cci">CCI-002450</cdf:ident>
      <cdf:fix id="F-50263r18_fix"></cdf:fix>
      <cdf:check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5">
            <cdf:check-content-ref href="#scap_mil.disa.stig_comp_U_MS_IE11_V1R16_STIG_SCAP_1-2_Benchmark-oval.xml" name="oval:mil.disa.fso.ie:def:580"></cdf:check-content-ref>
      </cdf:check>
</cdf:rule-result>
```

At the moment, using the XML snippet above, I'm getting the following output (per iteration):

```
severity = medium
weight = 10.0
time = 2022-05-28T23:12:16
version = DTBI014-IE11
idref = xccdf_mil.disa.stig_rule_SV-59337r8_rule
cdf:rule-result = failCCI-002450
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
severity = medium
weight = 10.0
time = 2022-05-28T23:12:16
version = DTBI014-IE11
idref = xccdf_mil.disa.stig_rule_SV-59337r8_rule
result = fail
checkIdentifier = CCI-002450
fixId = F-50263r18_fix
checkSchema = http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5
checkName = oval:mil.disa.fso.ie:def:580
```

Here's my playground/study code so far:

```
void Main()
{
    // This is shared above
    string path = @"C:\tmp\Example.xml"; 
    
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathDocument docNav;
    XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
    String strExpression;
    
    // Open the XML.
    docNav = new XPathDocument(path);
    
    // Create a navigator to query with XPath.
    nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
    strExpression = "/cdf:Benchmark/cdf:TestResult/cdf:rule-result";

    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("cdf", "http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2");

    // Select the node and place the results in an iterator.
    NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression, nsmgr);

    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNavigator navigator2 = NodeIter.Current.Clone();
        navigator2.MoveToFirstAttribute();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", navigator2.Name, navigator2.Value);

        while (navigator2.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", navigator2.Name, navigator2.Value);
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", NodeIter.Current.Name, NodeIter.Current.Value);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers, either I'm doing this all wrong, or this is bizarrely one of the toughest things I've ever had to do in .NET...

Comment: Are the node names dynamic? Do you know in advance the exact paths to the values you want? Or are you just looping over everything and parsing it

Comment: Well, for your first selection you use an XPath expression but then you kind try to work with the XPathNavigator API. Why are you not selecting attributes with e.g. `.//@*` and child elements with e.g. `*[normalize-space()` and take the union with e.g `.//@* | .//*[normalize-space()]`? And of course XPath 1 is old, in the .NET world using Saxon you can use XPath 3.1, Microsoft itself preferred to move its query abilities by giving you XQuery 1 comparable features with LINQ to XML as LINQ. These are more powerful, allow for more compact expressions.

Comment: @Charlieface I know in advance, its a strict schema, so the XML files will always have the same paths.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you kindly provide an example of how I would use `.//@*` to get multiple attributes, and do you have a good reference for me to further read up on `.//@* | .//*[normalize-space()]`?

Comment: XPath tutorials are around a lot on the web, if you want a free book with some detailedness you can try https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm, for instance. It covers more with XSLT as well but I don't know of a book dedicated to XPath alone. A reference is the W3C XPath 1.0 specification itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're iterating through the **attributes** of your `<cdf:rule-result>` nodes, but not the **child nodes**. I haven't used `XPathNavigator` for a long time, but I'd suggest looking into the
[XPathNavigator.SelectChildren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.selectchildren) and[XPathNavigator.SelectDescendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.selectdescendants) methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XPath 1.0 you can at least do e.g.

```
        foreach (XPathNavigator result in nav.Select(strExpression, nsmgr))
        {
            foreach (XPathNavigator value in result.Select(".//@* | .//*[normalize-space()]", nsmgr))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", value.LocalName, value.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

This will collect all data you have shown and two or three that are in the sample but your wanted output doesn't show; it won't rename things, obviously. It is not clear which values are wanted and which not so I have not attempted to exclude values so far in XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess around with C# code to do any of this, I would do it all in a single XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0" expand-text="yes" xmlns:cdf=""http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
severity = {cdf:rule-result/@severity}
weight = {cdf:rule-result/@weight}
time = {cdf:rule-result/@time}
version = {cdf:rule-result/@version}
idref = {cdf:rule-result/@idref}
result = {cdf:rule-result/@severity}
checkIdentifier = {cdf:rule-result/@cdf:ident}
fixId = {cdf:rule-result/cdf:fix/@id}
checkSchema = {cdf:rule-result/cdf:check/@system}  
checkName = {cdf:rule-result/cdf:check-content-ref/@name} 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It's not much more difficult in XSLT 1.0 if you prefer to use the Microsoft processor - just replace the stuff in curly braces with `<xsl:value-of select="..."/>`

Comment: The input is more complex than the shown snippet so you would need to use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>`, `match="/cdf:Benchmark/cdf:TestResult/cdf:rule-result"` and adapt the template expressions.